# Converting a collection of base class to a collection of derived class

Tags: c#

Could you please help me convert ObservableCollection of BaseClass to IEnumerable of DerivedClass?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Jon and Servy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that all the items are derived objects then use LINQ's `Enumerable.Cast`:

```
var enumerable = collection.Cast<DerivedClass>();
```

The above will throw if any item in the collection is not actually a `DerivedClass`.

If the collection may include non-derived objects and you only want those that are derived:

```
var enumerable = collection.OfType<DerivedClass>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure all of the items are actually of the derived type then use `Cast`

```
IEnumerable<DerivedClass> results = observableCollection.Cast<DerivedClass>();
```

If some might not be of that type then use

```
IEnumerable<DerivedClass> results = observableCollection.OfType<DerivedClass>();
```

`Cast` will throw an exception if any items can't be casted, `OfType` will simply not include them in the results.